# Make contour lines level with graph interval?

Tags: plotting

I am graphing the voltage traveling through some water with two electrodes.  I have the graph with contour lines and all, but is there any way that I can get the contour lines to be at the tick marks along the Z axis?

So, if every tick mark is 1volt, can I have contour lines at every integer voltage?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}];
zmesh = {-1/3, 0, 1/3};
facegrids =  Thread[{Join[#, -#] &@IdentityMatrix[3], {Range[5, 30, 5], zmesh}}, List, 1];

ListPlot3D[data, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {zmesh},
 FaceGrids -> facegrids, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},  PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of extra in this answer, but by using Mesh -> {Range[max]} it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This adapts the ticks and the mesh to the range of the $z$ values:

```
data2 = Table[10 + (3 ((j - 20)^2 - (j + 5)^2))/(75 + (i - 10)^2 + 2 (j - 10)^2),
          {i, 0, 20}, {j, 0, 20}];

(* computes ticks and stores the coordinates in zmesh *)
ticks[zmin_, zmax_] := Module[{mark, ldz, dz},
   ldz = Round[Log10[(zmax - zmin)/10], 1/3];
   dz = Round[10^ldz, 10^Floor[ldz]];
   mark = Round[10^(ldz + 2/3), 10^Floor[ldz + 2/3]];
   If[Chop@Mod[#, mark] == 0, #, {#, "", {0.005, 0}}] & /@ (zmesh = 
      N@Range[Ceiling[zmin, dz], zmax, dz])];

myTicks = ticks[Min[data2], Max[data2]]; (* sets mesh & ticks to same z-values *)

ListPlot3D[data2, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {zmesh}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, FaceGrids -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, myTicks}]
```

[image: Output]

This is kind of cute, except `ListPlot3D` evaluates twice,
since `zmesh` is reset by the function `ticks`.
But perhaps that's ok if you have the spare time.

```
Dynamic@ListPlot3D[data2, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {zmesh}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, FaceGrids -> All, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, ticks}]
```

It also works with other plot functions

```
Dynamic@Plot3D[5 Sin[x^2 + x y^2/2]/(1 + x^2 + y^2),
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, MaxRecursion -> 3, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {zmesh}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, FaceGrids -> All, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, ticks}]
```

[image: Output]